# How do i push Inside firebase forEach?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, foreach

```
async function copyHistory() {
  db.ref("His").on("value", (snap) => {
    snap.forEach((item) => {
      item.forEach((data) => {
        console.log(data.val(), item.key);
        postRef.push({ name: "Test Value" });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

postRef.push works only once?
Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Please provide some sample data so we can see what the code is iterating over.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.